loginctl-hooks + slock not working as expected
I have openrc init system and I want to lock my loginctl session with slock on running loginctl suspend.
I am using the loginctl hooks for the purpose.
loginctl man page :
Hook directories

[/usr]/lib[64]/elogind/system-sleep/, /etc/elogind/system-sleep/

Immediately before entering system suspend and/or hibernation elogind
will run all executables in [/usr]/lib[64]/elogind/system-sleep/ and 
/etc/elogind/system-sleep/ and pass two arguments to them. 
The first argument will be "pre", the second either "suspend", "hibernate", 
"hybrid-sleep", or "suspend-then-hibernate", depending on the chosen action. 
Immediately after leaving system suspend and/or hibernation the same executables 
are run, but the first argument is now "post". 
All executables in this directory are executed sequentially, and execution 
of the action is not continued until all executables have finished.



[/usr]/lib[64]/elogind/system-shutdown/, /etc/elogind/system-shutdown/

Immediately before rebooting or powering the system off, elogind will run all 
executables in [/usr]/lib[64]/elogind/system-shutdown/ and 
/etc/elogind/system-shutdown/ and pass one argument to them. 
The argument will either be "poweroff" or "reboot", depending on the chosen action.



AllowPowerOffInterrupts, AllowSuspendInterrupts

Whether the executables in these directories run successfully or not is of no 
concern to elogind. If you want the scripts to cause the action to be 
cancelled if one fails, you can set "AllowPowerOffInterrupts" and/or 
"AllowSuspendInterrupts" to "yes" in /etc/elogind/logind.conf. 
For this to work the executables in question must print an error message
to "STDOUT" that begins with either of these keywords: "CANCELLED", 
"CRITICAL", "ERROR" or "FAILED". If you want any of these words in a 
message without causing the action to be cancelled, just re-arrange 
the sentence in question so that the keyword is not the first word.



BroadcastPowerOffInterrupts, BroadcastSuspendInterrupts

By default an interrupt of a power off or a suspend is broadcasted. 
If you do not whish these broadcasts to happen, change 
"BroadcastPowerOffInterrupts" and/or "BroadcastSuspendInterrupts" to "no"
in /etc/elogind/logind.conf.



Note that scripts or binaries dropped in any of the hook directories are
intended for local use only and should be considered hacks. If applications
want to react to these system commands, they should rather use the
Inhibitor interface[1].

/lib64/elogind/system-sleep/laptop_suspend.sh script :
#!/bin/bash
case $1/$2 in
        pre/suspend)
                /usr/bin/slock &
                ;;
        pre/hibernate)
                /usr/bin/slock &
                ;;
        post/*)
                ;;
esac

My issue : Say if leave the laptop lid closed for 30 mins, on resuming from suspend, the xorg session is locked. But if I just wake the laptop after 10 seconds of suspend, then the there is no lock.
Why is the behaviour inconsistent ?
Is there any race condition between slock executing and suspend executing ? If yes, how to eliminate the race condition?
DIRTY HACK:

Defined an alias
alias suspend="sudo sh -c 'echo /dev/nvme0n1p2 > /sys/power/resume && slock & echo mem > /sys/power/state'"
Disadvantages : I have to manually run it in my terminal before closing my laptop lid.

